# SharePoint customised top nagivation for managed navigation not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, navigation, managed-navigation

I'm using Bootstrap to brand my SharePoint 2013 publishing site.
I'm having a problem with the top navigation when its set to managed navigation.
Basically it work fine on the first page load, after I start navigating between the links it will show empty.

However its working fine with structural navigation.

Appreciate any help on this

Thanks

Comment: Can you add more info about your customizations? Maybe some screenshots? If you are using only css then it maybe a problem with styles, because managed navigation can create another html layout than structural. If you are using some JavaScript, then it looks like issue with MDS.

Comment: Im using this http://www.topsharepoint.com/shareboot-responsive-sharepoint-2013-theme